# Trying to access elements of an object in Laravel but hitting "Undefined property: stdClass::$code"

Tags: laravel, object

I made an array of objects which each of the objects contain a country code(code) element and also a country name(name) element. I am trying to access the variable passed from the controller to my blade file and am able to access the name element of the object but when I try to access the code element I hit the same "Undefined property: stdClass::$code" error.

Below is a small part of the array that is passed from the controller to the blade file:-

```
[
{
name: "Afghanistan",
code: "93"
},
{
name: "Albania",
code: "355"
},
{
name: "Algeria",
code: "213"
}
]
```

The code for me to achieve the array above :-

```
public static function getAllCountry()
    {
        $array = array();
        $all_countries = countries(false, true);

        foreach ($all_countries as $country => $item) {
            $country_short_name = (string) $country;
            $temp_country_code = country($country_short_name)->getCallingCodes();
            $country_code = $temp_country_code;
            $country_name = country($country_short_name)->getName();
            $object = new \stdClass();
            $object->name = $country_name;
            foreach ($country_code as $i => $v) {
                $object->code = $v;
            }
            $array[] = $object;
        }

        sort($array);

        return $array;
    }
```

Here is me trying to access the elements of the objects with a foreach statement in my blade file :-

```
@foreach ($countries as $key => $country)
    <p>{{$country->code}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Make sure that `$country_code` value is not empty before the foreach, otherwise you won't set the code property on your object. To debug it use `dd($country_code)` before the foreach

Comment: I see but I dont really understand how does that solve the situation cuz I can already see the whole array and its contents but just when I'm in my foreach I hit that error

Comment: What if you do {{ dd($country) }} in your blade foreach? What is its output?

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($countries as $key => $country)
    <p>{{$country['code']}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Tried but hitting "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" error now :(